# How can I add a cell array of strings in a legend in Matlab?

Tags: string, matlab, legend, cell-array

I'm trying to use a cell array of strings in order to build a legend for each sample in a graph, something like this:

```
x = [1 5 3 5 6];
y = [3 6 3 6 4];
Legend = cell(5,1);
Legend{1} = 'a';
Legend{2} = 'b';
Legend{3} = 'c';
Legend{4} = 'd';
Legend{5} = 'e';
figure
hold on
for k=1:5
    plot(x(k),y(k),'o')
end
legend(Legend)
```

But I'm getting the following message error from matlab:

```
Error using subsindex
Function 'subsindex' is not defined for values of class 'cell'.
```

Is there something that I can do to fix it?

Thanks

Comment: Actually, your code works on MATLAB 2015b. Have you tried `legend(Legend{:})`? This is called [comma separated lists](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/comma-separated-lists.html)

Comment: zeeMonkeez is right, `legend(Legend{:})` solves that problem; also, you can simply create the legend as: `Legend={'a','b','c','d','e'}`

Comment: No problem for MATLAB 2014b either. Which version are you running? Further, as far as I know you only pay for the license these days at mathowrks. In case you do not have any special reasons for this (or have an older version following other agreements) you may want to update.

Comment: Not for the question, but for good practice and Matlab coding... Instead of the loop you can just write `plot(x,y,'o')`

Comment: Thanks guys! It was just about the comma separated lists, I only did what zeeMonkeez suggested and voilà, it works! Thanks Cyb3rFly3r too about the tip. I appreciated your help o/